# How to use the rotateCamera function of Trackball Controls in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, trackball

I am looking for autorotate functionality like in Orbital controls. I found the rotateCamera() in Threejs Docs. Not sure how to use it or call it. Can anyone tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

`TrackballControls` does not support auto rotate. The mentioned method `rotateCamera()` is intended for internal use only. It's actually called by `update()`.

You have two options now:

- Use `OrbitControls`
- Create a custom version of `TrackballControls` and implement the auto rotate feature by yourself.